# Why is this simple function not outputting anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello below is the simple code I am trying to use.

I don't understand why nothing is being outputted in the console as In the tutorial it is returning 120. I am trying to do a recursion function. Any help you can give me would be great, I am using python 3.7 for reference.

Code:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)

factorial(5)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: square(4) returns 16 however it prints nothing to the console so to print you would write print(square(4))

Comment: `res=factorial(5); print(res)`

Answer (score 4):

why nothing is being outputted in the console a

well, there is no print statement in your code....

do print the output

```
print(square(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't outputting anything because nowhere is a command/function call to output anything.

One solution would be

```
def square(num):
    return num**2

print(square(4))
```

another (inferior) solution would be

```
def square(num):
    print(num**2)

square(4)
```

Note that the first solution is better, because the function does one thing: calculate the square of a number.

The second solution calculates and prints the square, but imagine you want to use the number somewhere else, then the function is of no use. Thus use the first version.

Comment: @EranMoshe: I was about to ask the same question (and hence I upvoted)

Comment: @EranMoshe Oh? Now that you say it, I see it as well. Strange… But I stopped wondering about something getting downvoted, that happens all the time (alas).